# How to access params in angular-fullstack's endpoint?

Tags: javascript, express, yo, angular-fullstack

I created an endpoint using `yo angular-fullstack:endpoint question` my question is how can I configure/access the params?

for example when requesting `/api/questions/1` and inspecting the `req` object displays an empty object (`{}`).

Here are (what I think are) the relevant bits:

**server/routes.js**

```
 9   module.exports = function(app) {                                                
10                                                                                 
11   // Insert routes below                                                        
12   app.use('/api/questions/:step', require('./api/question')); 
   ...
```

**api/question/question.controller.js**

```
55  // Get list of questions                                                        
56  exports.index = function(req, res) {                                            
57     console.log(req.params)   
58     console.log(req.query)
   ...
```

**api/question/index.js**

```
 1 'use strict';                                                                   
 2                                                                                 
 3 var express = require('express');                                               
 4 var controller = require('./question.controller');                              
 5                                                                                 
 6 var router = express.Router();                                                  
 7                                                                                 
 8 router.get('/', controller.index);                                              
 9                                                                                 
10 module.exports = router;
```

Both logs display `{}`.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but after much searching and experimenting I can't figure it out.

Comment: Solved: line 8 of index.js should be router.get('/:step', controller.index);

Comment: If you found your own answer, consider writing an answer using the buttons below. It will help readers in the future find the problem you had faster.